# Getting integer for a switch without using scanf

Tags: c, scanf, fgets

So I have written some code that has a `switch`, and I need to give it an integer to select a `case` within the `switch`. I can't use `scanf()` because I have multiple `fgets()` further down the line and the `'\n'` from the `scanf()` input breaks the code.

Here is my code:

**main.c**

```
#include "functions.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int choice;
    char temp[10];
    
    do {
        printf("Menu\n\n");
        printf("1. Read student information from file\n");
        printf("2. Write student information to file\n");
        printf("3. Exit\n");
        fgets(choice, 10, stdin);
    
        switch (choice) {
          case 1:
            fileRead();
            break;
          case 2:
            fileWrite();
            break;
          default:
            printf("Program stopped!\n");
            break;
        }
    } while (choice != 3);
    return 0;
}
```

**functions.h**

```
#ifndef UNTITLED17_FUNCTIONS_H
#define UNTITLED17_FUNCTIONS_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct student {
    char studentID[100];
    char studentName[100];
    char age[100];
} student_t;

void fileRead() {
    FILE *f = fopen("student_read.txt", "r");
    if (f == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to open file(s)!\n");
    }
    printf("Type your student ID:");
    fgets(student_t.studentID, 100, stdin);

    printf("Type your name:");
    fgets(student_t.studentName, 100, stdin);

    printf("Type your age:");
    fgets(student_t.age, 100, stdin);

    printf("Student id: %s\n", student_t.studentID);
    printf("Name: %s\n", student_t.studentName);
    printf("Age: %s\n", student_t.age);
}

void fileWrite() {
    FILE *f = fopen("student_write.txt", "w");
    if (f == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to open file(s)!\n");
    }
    printf("Type your student ID:");
    fgets(student_t.studentID, 100, stdin);
    printf("Type your name:");
    fgets(student_t.studentName, 100, stdin);
    printf("Type your age:");
    fgets(student_t.age, 100, stdin);

    printf("Student id: %s\n", student_t.studentID);
    printf("Name: %s\n", student_t.studentName);
    printf("Age: %s\n", student_t.age);
}

#endif //UNTITLED17_FUNCTIONS_H
```

Any ideas?

Thanks :)

Comment: Use `fgets` and `sscanf` the buffer, then the other `fgets` calls will work as expected.

Comment: Don't put function definitions into `h` file. It is for declarations (prototypes) only.

Comment: The compiler didn't complain about `fgets(choice, 10, stdin);`?

Comment: @ScottHunter yeah but i just ran out of ideas

Comment: @Cheatah buffer?

Comment: There's nothing preventing you from using `scanf`, but you need to use it correctly.  If you want to consume the newline, `scanf("%d",...)` won't do that, but there's nothing preventing you from consuming it some other way. (Eg, call `fgetc` in a loop)

Comment: @Ole-Johan Yes. `choice` will contain a string, not a number. You will have to `sscanf(choice, "%d", &n);` where `n` is an `int`, for example.

Comment: Or you can just use `atoi(choice)` to convert the string to an integer.  (This isn't perfect, and will quietly give you 0 even if there was no number typed at all, but it's quick & easy.)

Comment: @Ole-Johan Congratulations, though, for being aware of the `scanf`/`fgets` interlace problem.  We get dozens of questions per day asking why `fgets` doesn't work.  This is the first time I can remember seeing a question from someone who already knew about that issue, and was trying to do something better.

Comment: @SteveSummit yeah because i just asked a question about it an hour ago LOL

Answer (score 1):

As OP [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70205431/getting-integer-for-a-switch-without-using-scanf/70205794#comment124105098_70205676) the qualified nature of input, I'd go with a [simple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70205431/getting-integer-for-a-switch-without-using-scanf/70205794#comment124105183_70205431) `fgets(), atoi()`.  Read into a buffer and convert to an `int`.

```
//fgets(choice, 10, stdin);
//switch(choice){

// Initialize just in case no input.
// Not so big to prevent atoi() overflow - which is UB. 
char buf[5] = ""; 

fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
choice = atoi(buf);
switch(choice) {
```

If input was not qualified, I'd use a larger buffer, `strtol()` and more error checking.

In that case, makes sense to make a helper function to get an `int`.

Some untested code:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

// On EOF, return EOF
// Else return 1 for success, 0 failure.
int getint(const char *prompt, int *dest) {
  // Some buffer generously sized to the type.
  char buf[sizeof *dest * CHAR_BIT];

  if (prompt) {
    fputs(prompt, stdout);
  }
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
    return EOF;
  }
  char *endptr;
  errno = 0;
  long val = strtol(buf, &endptr, 0);
  if (buf == endptr) {
    return 0;  // No conversion
  }
  if (errno == ERANGE) {
    return 0;  // out of long range
  }
  #if LONG_MIN < INT_MIN || LONG_MAX > INT_MAX
  if (val > INT_MAX || val < INT_MIN) {
    errno = ERANGE;
    return 0; // Out of int range
  }
  #endif
  *dest = (int) val;
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: OOPS! my bad, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

`fgets`, as the `s` suggests, is meant for reading a *string* from a file, which is why the compiler complains about the first argument: it should be a pointer to where that string will go.  Once there, as @Cheetah suggests, parse that to get the integer value it represents.

Answer (score 0):

This line from your code reads a line into the `choice` buffer:

```
fgets(choice, 10, stdin);
```

You can add this directly afterwards:

```
int n;
if (sscanf(choice, "%d", &n) != 1)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

Most notably here is the `sscanf` that reads the `choice` buffer that should contain a string, since it was returned by `fgets`. The value is stored in `n`. You can check that in your `switch` statement.

I added an `if` around the `sscanf`, to check that `1` is returned, that is the number of arguments that were read successfully.

Comment: I ended up doing this:

`int choice;
char choiceTemp[10];

fgets(choiceTemp, 10, stdin);
sscanf(choiceTemp, "%i", &choice);`

Comment: Yes that should do the job. But beware that people can input invalid lines.

Comment: yeah, the input is prederetmined cause the program is tested using a python program so i have som leeway

Comment: `choice` was an `int`, not a buffer of any kind.

Comment: @ScottHunter im very very new to coding so i dont really know what that means, but atleast it works

Comment: By a *very* liberal definition of `works`.  The way @Ole-Johan implemented your idea is correct.

Answer (score 0):

`fgets(choice, 10, stdin);` is definitely incorrect as `choice` is an `int`, not a pointer to `char` nor a `char` array.

You should read the string and convert its contents as an integer this way:

```
    if (!fgets(temp, sizeof temp, stdin))
        return 1;
    choice = atoi(temp);
```

Also note these remarks:

- if the file cannot be open in `fileRead()` and `fileWrite()`, you should return after you output the error message.
- functions should not be defined in header files, only declarations belong there
- you should test the return value of `fgets()` to detect end of file.
- `fileRead` and `fileWrite` should return an success/failure indicator.
- you should strip the newline left by `fgets()` at the end of the array.  Even better: you should write a function that reads a line into the destination array, truncating to available space and stripping initial and trailing whitespace.

Comment: yeah i fixed it by making a temp char for the fgets and converting it using sscanf